# basename $0 results in '-bash'

Tags: bash, scripting, raspbian

It seems a Bash script on Raspbian I'm using is unable to retrieve it's own name with basename when I'm running it from /etc/profile.d

I always used this to get the name of my script:

```
ScriptName="$($(which basename) -- ${0})"
```

It works fine when executing manually. When I capture $0 the results is '-bash'
What could be happening here. What would be a better way to get the scriptname?

I tried with

```
FullScriptName="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
```

and then

```
ScriptName = "$( basename $FullScriptName)"
```

but somehow I'm getting:

```
ScriptName: command not found
```

Comment: How exactly is the script being run? Also, see [BashFAQ #28: How do I determine the location of my script? I want to read some config files from the same place.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assign and Quote Your Variables Properly

Fix your syntax and your quoting:

```
ScriptName=$(basename "$0")
```

### See Also

- [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions)
- [Quote Removal](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quote-Removal)